# How to import class using ES6 syntax? (without Babel)

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I have file with a ES6 class with default export:

```
accessmanager.js

   export default class AccessManagerClient {
      constructor(){
        ...
      }
    }
```

And I want to import it like this:

```
anotherFile.js

import AccessManagerClient from '../someFolder/accessmanager';
```

When I run my spec I get an error:

```
import AccessManagerClient from '../someFolder/accessmanager';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I have such npm and node versions:

```
$ npm -v
5.3.0

$ node -v
v8.0.0
```

Comment: Not possible to work with `import` and `export` without babel (or another transpiler that does the same as babel). You can use old school `const AccessManagerClient = require('...');` The more interesting question is, why not use babel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't without Babel or some other packager/bundler/transpiler, because Node doesn't have native support for `import`/`export` yet. Either use Node's own [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), or a packager/bundler/transpiler.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old question. But in case others still look for alternative, now with the new Node version, we can use without Babel:

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

So what you need to do is upgrading your Node version. FYI: This Node version v10.9.0 is still experimental.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official node site](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/), all ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) features are split into three groups for shipping, staged, and in progress features:

- All shipping features, which V8 considers stable, are turned on by default on Node.js and do NOT require any kind of runtime flag.
- Staged features, which are almost-completed features that are not considered stable by the V8 team, require a runtime flag: --harmony.
- In progress features can be activated individually by their respective harmony flag, although this is highly discouraged unless for testing purposes. Note: these flags are exposed by V8 and will potentially change without any deprecation notice.